# ExtJs JSONStore Input Data Format

Tags: extjs4

Here is my code:

```
function getStore (json) {
    var reader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({
       root : 'data',
       successProperty: 'success',
       totalProperty: "rows",
       fields : [
        {name: 'num', allowBlank:'true'},
        {name: 'date', dateFormat:'d.m.Y H:i:s', type: 'date'},
        {name: 'signerFIO', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'checkSign', type: 'boolean'}
       ]
   });

   var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore ({
     data   : json,
     reader : reader
   });

   return store;
}
```

The data arrived from the server is: {`"data":[{"num":"111","signerFIO":"hello","checkSign":true,"date":"25.05.2012"}],"success":1,"rows":1}`

I've tried to set a 'json' function parameter to a raw json (as it arrived) and to a Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText)

I've tried this code in the FF and in the FireBug I've got the strange `h is undefined` error.

Does anybody know what is wrong?

**UPDATE**

This

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore ({
    data     : json,
    fields   : ['data']
});
```

worked for me in terms that there was no errors, but no data was loaded either.

Comment: have you tried using the debug version of extjs? it should give you a bit more detail. Also how are you loading the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the reader (actually, I don't know what a problem).
This:

```
function getStore (jsonRequestUrl) {
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore ({
    autoLoad : false,
    proxy    : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({ url: jsonRequestUrl, method: 'POST' }),
    root     : 'data',
    successProperty : 'success',
    totalProperty   : "rows",
    idProperty      : "id",
    fields : [
        {name: 'num', type: 'string', mapping: 'num'},
        {name: 'signerFIO', type: 'string', mapping: 'signerFIO'},
        {name: 'checkSign', type: 'boolean', mapping: 'checkSign'},
        {name: 'date', dateFormat:'d.m.Y', type: 'date', mapping: 'date'}
    ]
});
store.load();

return store;
}
```

worked for me.

Comment: You have to be careful here, store.load() is async and the store will be returned before the data is loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much! And what method is synchronious?

Comment: not sure that you can make it sync, but typically the idea is to listen for completion of load event and then do something useful. You can either set a listener on the store or pass in a callback function to the load method. Check out Sencha docs and examples of this done right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure what you're trying to do with this code, but this will make it work (assuming json is a decoded object and not a string):

```
Ext.define("MyItem", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    fields: [
        {name: 'num', allowBlank:'true'},
            {name: 'date', dateFormat:'d.m.Y H:i:s', type: 'date'},
            {name: 'signerFIO', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'checkSign', type: 'boolean'}
    ]
});
function getStore (json) {

   var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore ({
     data:  json.data,
     model: MyItem
   });

   return store;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll try your variant. And, of course, here is the point up for you =) I've managed to solve the problem (see my response), but I don't know, where was an error.